# using pdf.js' viewer.html gives NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied when accessing it from

Tags: html, cors, pdf.js

The way I use pdf.js to load a pdf from its local directory is:

```
<iframe src="js/pdfjs-1.1.114-dist/web/viewer.html?file=../../../docs/jobs/E0001.pdf" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

but on the website it shows only the pdf frame and no actual content is displayed. If I select download, the correct file is downloaded, so the file page is valid.

From debugger, it says:
NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI: Access to restricted URI denied

Which looks like CORS issue... but I don't know how to fix this..

Comment: I'm experiencing the same sort of issue. Try to put the file to a folder so that your path doesn't contain `../` parts (meaning that the pdf is in the same folder or subfolder of the folder where viewer.html is). This way it should work, but I guess that's no what you want (neither do I). Yet, if that solves your issue, let me add a corresponding answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I've figured it out for FireFox: for me, going to `about:config` and setting `security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy` to `false` solved the issue.